# Install Blender on macOS 10.10.5

Tags: installation, osx

Trying to install Blender on my Mac and I am being told that I cannot do it with my operating system (macOS 10.10.5). Is it possible?

Answer (score 1):

You can't install the latest version as that requires macOS 10.12 +.

You can install Blender 2.79:

> Blender 2.79 runs on all systems that support OpenGL 2.1 and above, with recent graphics drivers. **For macOS, version 10.9 and later are supported.**

([Source](https://www.blender.org/download/requirements/))